# How to sort by date and then by date add totals of another column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How can i take a row of dates and filter them by months, and add a total of sales of every month?

This code is trying to do it for january.

```
df['Release Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Release Date'])
print(df.loc[df['Release Date'].dt.month == 1][df['Tickets Sold'].sum())

df['Release Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Release Date'])
print(df.loc[df['Release Date'].dt.month == 1][df['Tickets Sold'].sum())
```

0                           1,000 Rupee Note  ...          277
1                        10 Cloverfield Lane  ...      8333294
2  13 Hours: The Secret Soldiers of Benghazi  ...      6110198
3                          2016 Oscar Shorts  ...       325643
4                         20th Century Women  ...        20644

Trying to add up total of tickets sold for every month.

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to get the totals for each month. Are you then also trying to do some with these totals?

Dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# dummy data
date_range = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-03-31', freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(1, 20, (date_range.shape[0], 1)),
    index=date_range,
    columns=['Tickets Sold'])
df['Release Date'] = df.index
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

>>> print(df.head())
   Tickets Sold Release Date
0            15   2019-01-01
1             7   2019-01-02
2             5   2019-01-03
3             5   2019-01-04
4            19   2019-01-05
```

To get the totals, just make the `Release Date` column the `index` and use `resample` on a monthly `M` basis.

```
# set column release date as index and resample.
df.set_index('Release Date', inplace=True)

>>> print(df.resample('M').sum())
              Tickets Sold
Release Date              
2019-01-31             305
2019-02-28             278
2019-03-31             322
```